# How can we convert XML file to CSV?

Tags: java, xml, csv

I am having an XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Results>
    <Row>
        <COL1></COL1>
        <COL2>25.00</COL2>
        <COL3>2009-07-06 15:49:34.984</COL3>
        <COL4>00001720</COL4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <COL1>RJ</COL1>
        <COL2>26.00</COL2>
        <COL3>2009-07-06 16:04:16.156</COL3>
        <COL4>00001729</COL4>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <COL1>SD</COL1>
        <COL2>28.00</COL2>
        <COL3>2009-07-06 16:05:04.375</COL3>
        <COL4>00001721</COL4>
    </Row>  
</Results>
```

I have to convert this XML into CSV file. I have heard we can do such thing using XSLT. How can i do this in Java ( with/without XSLT )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
loop through the rows:
    loop through all children of `Row`:
        write out the text
        append a comma
    new line
```

That quick little loop will write a comma at the end of each line, but I'm sure you can figure out how to remove that.

For actually parsing the XML, I suggest using [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/). It has a pretty intuitive API.

Comment: I think the issue is the understanding of how to parse the XML, not so much the writing of the resultant values

Comment: You forgot escaping (what if there is a comma in the data?).

Answer (score 5):

Using XSLT is often a bad idea. Use [Apache Commons Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/). It's fairly easy to use - here's a rough idea::

```
Digester digester = new Digester();

digester.addObjectCreate("Results/Row", MyRowHolder.class);
digester.addCallMethod("Results/Row/COL1","addCol", 0);
// Similarly for COL2, etc.
digester.parse("mydata.xml");
```

This will create a `MyRowHolder` instance (where this is a class you provide). This class would have a `addCol()` method which would be called for each `<COLn>` with the contents of that tag.

Comment: "Using XSLT is often a bad idea" - May I ask why? :)

Comment: Plus, the poster asked how to do it in Java WITHOUT XSLT. So I'm not sure why I got down-voted :-(

Comment: Digester is underused. +1 for this

Comment: @Vinay Sajip: Agreed, XSLT is a bit harder to debug. However, converting the above to CSV is so trivial that the required XSLT would probably not need much debugging anyway.

Comment: @Vinay Sajip: Also, the question was with OR without XSLT, and generally seems to be in favor of XSLT even. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak - You're right, I must've read "with/without" as "without".

Answer (score 3):

In XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />

  <xsl:template match="/Results">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Row" />  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />  
    <xsl:if test="not(last())">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />  
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="not(last())">
      <xsl:value-of select="','" />  
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your COL* values can contain commas, you could wrap the values in double quotes:

```
  <xsl:template match="Row/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('"', ., '"')" />
    <!-- ... --->
```

If they can contain commas *and* double quotes, things could get a bit more complex due to the required escaping. You know your data, you'll be able to decide how to best format the output. Using a different separator (e.g. TAB or a pipe symbol) is also an option.

Comment: P.S.: I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to find sample that shows how to use XSLT from within Java. It's not hard. :)

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT you can use the JAXP interface to the XSLT processor and then use <xsl:text> in your stylesheet to convert to text output.

```
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

generates a newline. for example.

Answer (score 1):

Read the XML file in.

Loop throught each record and add it to a csv file.

Comment: Agreed. Using XSLT in this situation is overkill. No need to learn a new language just to output CSV from a format this simple.

Comment: and how we will do that Derek

Comment: I don't think this is desperately helpful if you're not familiar with the available XML apis :-(

Comment: You forgot escaping (what if there is a comma in the data?).

Answer (score 1):

Use the straightforward [SAX](http://developers.sun.com/sw/building/codesamples/sax/) API via the standard Java [JAXP](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JAXPIntro.html) package. This will allow you to write a class that receives events for each XML element your reader encounters.

Briefly:

1. read your XML in using SAX
2. record text values via the SAX [DefaultHandler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) characters() method
3. when you get an end event for a COL, record this string value
4. when you get the ROW end event, simply write out a comma separated line of previously recorded values

Comment: @Brian: If it is possible, please give the example.

Comment: I'd have a look at the tutorials linked, and implement a simple DefaultHandler. When you run it, you'll see (in a debugger, or via print outs) how the event methods are called, and that should make it clear. Sorry - I can't easily post a sample